# How would I find the second largest salary from the employee table?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server-2005

How would I go about querying for the second largest salary from all employees in my Employee table?

Answer (score 65):

Try this:

```
SELECT max(salary)
FROM emptable
WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary)
                FROM emptable);
```

Comment: The above one gives the second largest value, Suppose if i have multiple values in the second largest, what will be the query modification to meet the above mentioned requirement.
For example , i have sal list as follows 
200,100,100,90
so the query will result in 100, not 100,100. So what will be the modification to achieve this.

Answer (score 54):

Simple Answer:

```
SELECT distinct(sal)
FROM emp
ORDER BY sal DESC
LIMIT 1, 1;
```

You will get only the second max salary.

And if you need any 3rd or 4th or Nth value you can increase the first value followed by `LIMIT (n-1)` ie. for 4th salary : `LIMIT 3, 1;`

Comment: This want work if you have 2 records with same salary. It want give you second max.

Comment: @mukeshpatel distinct needs to be applied thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Short and Great

Comment: @mukeshpatel Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 16):

Most of the other answers seem to be db specific.

General SQL query should be as follows:

```
select
   sal 
from
   emp a 
where
   N = (
      select
         count(distinct sal) 
      from
         emp b 
      where
         a.sal <= b.sal
   )
where
   N = any value
```

and this query should be able to work on any database.

Answer (score 12):

Try something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 compensation FROM (
  SELECT TOP 2 compensation FROM employees
  ORDER BY compensation DESC
) AS em ORDER BY compensation ASC
```

Essentially:

- Find the top 2 salaries in descending order.
- Of those 2, find the top salary in ascending order.
- The selected value is the second-highest salary.

If the salaries aren't distinct, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT TOP ...` instead.

Comment: When the TOP 1 compensation is earned by more than 1 employee, this query will return a wrong result.

Comment: If salaries aren't distinct, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT TOP...` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you should use `DENSE_RANK`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT
         [Salary],
         (DENSE_RANK()
         OVER
         (
           ORDER BY [Salary] DESC)) AS rnk
       FROM [Table1]
       GROUP BY [Num]
     ) AS A
WHERE A.rnk = 2
```

Comment: Replace RANK() with DENSE_RANK() and it works.

Comment: I'v changed query accordingly

Comment: Depends on whether one views the highest salary as the 2nd-highest in case of a tie. In that case `ROW_NUMBER()` should be used instead (`RANK()` won't return a 2 in that case, `DENSE_RANK()` will, but it will actually be the 3rd-highest salary).

Answer (score 6):

To find second max salary from employee,

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee
WHERE salary NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX (salary) FROM employee
)
```

To find first and second max salary from employee,

```
SELECT salary FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC
) WHERE rownum<=2
```

This queries are working fine because i have used

Comment: in fact, if you have a table:
1. 100
2. 100
3. 50

your query will return **null**, which is incorrect answer in this case

Answer (score 5):

```
select max(Emp_Sal) 
from Employee a
where 1 = ( select count(*) 
         from Employee b
         where b.Emp_Sal > a.Emp_Sal)
```

Yes running man.

Answer (score 5):

//To select name of employee whose salary is second highest

```
SELECT name
FROM employee WHERE salary =
       (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM 
             (SELECT TOP (2) salary
              FROM employee
              ORDER BY salary DESC) )
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    salary,
    employeeid
FROM
    employees
ORDER BY
    salary DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Then just get the second row.

Comment: What if the first two salaries are same?

Answer (score 4):

```
select distinct(t1.sal) 
from emp t1 
where &n=(select count(distinct(t2.sal)) from emp t2 where t1.sal<=t2.sal);
```

Output:
Enter value for n:  if you want 2nd highest ,enter 2; if you want 5,enter n=3

Answer (score 2):

```
   select * from compensation where Salary = (
      select top 1 Salary from (
      select top 2 Salary from compensation 
      group by Salary order by Salary desc) top2
      order by Salary)
```

which will give you **all** rows with second highest salary, which a few people may share

Answer (score 2):

```
    select max(Salary) from Employee 
where Salary
 not in (Select Max(Salary) from Employee)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(Salary) from Employee 
where Salary
  not in (Select top4 salary from Employee);
```

because answer is as follows

max(5,6,7,8)

so 5th highest record will be displayed, first four will not be considered

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select max(Emp_Sal) 
from Employee a
where 1 = ( select count(*) 
         from Employee b
         where b.Emp_Sal > a.Emp_Sal)
```

Comment: This doesnt work if there are duplicate salaries. Lets say there are three same max salary 30000 and you are finding the second highest.

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(sal) from emp
where sal not in (select max(sal) from emp )
```

**OR**

```
select max(salary) from emp table 
where sal<(select max(salary)from emp)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 salary
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 2 salary
        FROM
            employees
    ) sal
ORDER BY
    salary DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from emp 
where sal=(select min(sal) from 
(select sal from(select distinct sal from emp order by sal desc)
where rownum<=n));
```

n can be the value you want to see......

you can see all the fields of that person who having nth highest salary**strong text**