# Mysql Find multiple rows from each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns, `student_id`, `section_id`, and `marks`, each contains integer values, with `student_id` being the primary field with unique values. Now I was need to write queries for the 3 scenarios below (PS: this is for learning purposes only, so it would be great if you can show me some alternate logical approaches if possible):

1. Find the student who ranked 3rd in each section.
2. Find the student who ranked 2nd,3rd,and 4th in each section.
3. Find the student who ranked 4th in each section if there is any with the constraint that if there are multiple students with same marks in a section, then the next ranks are skipped. So let's say 3 students got the same marks which would rank them 2nd in a section, then the 3rd, and 4th ranks are skipped, and the next student to score less than them would be ranked 5th.

For the first one I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `students` s 
 WHERE s.student_id=
(
  SELECT student_id 
    FROM students 
   WHERE s.section_id=section_id 
   ORDER BY marks DESC 
   LIMIT 2,1
) 
 GROUP BY section_id 
 ORDER BY marks DESC
```

This works though I am not sure about optimization.

For the next one I tried using `IN` cause otherwise I can't fetch more than one row in the sub-query, but it says mysql doesn't support `LIMIT` in `IN` clause, is there any way to modify this query for the second scenario?

And lastly, I have no idea what to do about the third one.

I created a test table at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6442fb/1

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160262/query-for-second-maximum-salary-from-employee-table

Comment: This works, but it's an 'undocumented' solution (unless you count the user comments section on the page of the manual that deals with this stuff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL still lacks support for analytic functions. Specifically `RANK()` and `RANK_DENSE()` would be very helpful. One way to emulate them is by using user variables:

```
SELECT student_id, section_id, marks
  FROM
(
  SELECT s.*, @n := IF(@s = section_id, IF(@m = marks, @n, @n + 1), 1) rank, 
         @s := section_id, @m := marks
    FROM students s CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @s := NULL, @m := NULL) i
   ORDER BY section_id, marks DESC
) q
 WHERE rank = 3
 ORDER BY marks DESC;

SELECT student_id, section_id, marks
  FROM
(
  SELECT s.*, @n := IF(@s = section_id, IF(@m = marks, @n, @n + 1), 1) rank, 
         @s := section_id, @m := marks
    FROM students s CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @s := NULL, @m := NULL) i
   ORDER BY section_id, marks DESC
) q
 WHERE rank BETWEEN 2 AND 4
 ORDER BY section_id, marks DESC;

SELECT student_id, section_id, marks
  FROM
(
  SELECT s.*, @n := IF(@s = section_id, @n + 1, 1),
         @rn := IF(@m = marks, @rn, @n) rank,
         @s := section_id, @m := marks
    FROM students s CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @rn := 0, @s := NULL, @m := NULL) i
   ORDER BY section_id, marks DESC
) q
 WHERE rank = 4
 ORDER BY marks DESC;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6442fb/24)** demo

Comment: Wow that looks and works great! But can you please explain the query a bit? I tried looking up user variables, but then got lost at the cross joins above.

Comment: @Bluemagica `CROSS JOIN` is used just to initialize  variables. In inner select we properly order the resultset and as the rows are being selected we calculate the rank by comparing current values of `section_id` and `marks` with values from previous row (`@s` and `@m`); if we encounter a new section id we reset the counter to 1 otherwise we check if current value of marks equals to the value of a previous row than we keep the rank the same, otherwise we add `1` to it. In outer select we just filter out everything but the target rank. First two queries emulate `RANK_DENSE()` and third one `RAN