# Find max and second max salary for a employee table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose that you are given the following simple database table called Employee that has 2 columns named Employee ID and Salary:

```
  Employee
  Employee ID    Salary
   3            200
   4            800
   7            450
```

I wish to write a query select max(salary) as max_salary, 2nd_max_salary from employee

then it should return

```
  max_salary   2nd_max_salary
   800             450
```

i know how to find 2nd highest salary

```
   SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
  WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee )
```

or to find the nth

```
  SELECT FROM Employee Emp1 WHERE (N-1) = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary)) FROM Employee Emp2
  WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

but i am unable to figureout how to join these 2 results for the desired result

Comment: The obvious followup question is, if there was a 4th row in that sample data with a salary of 800...what's your desired result? Should it be `800,800` since those are your two highest salaries? Or should it be `800,450` since those are your two highest *unique* salaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I find the second largest salary from the employee table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160262/how-would-i-find-the-second-largest-salary-from-the-employee-table)

Comment: The above one gives the second largest value, Suppose if i have multiple values in the second largest, what will be the query modification to meet the above mentioned requirement

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can just run 2 queries as inner queries to return 2 columns:

```
select
  (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee) maxsalary,
  (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
  WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee )) as [2nd_max_salary]
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2445c/2)

Comment: What if it is a temporary table?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: It does make a difference you cannot refer to a temporary table twice in a query :)

Comment: What do you mean by CTE? You can read the documentation for what I stated here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: @Sohaib Sorry, I somehow forgot this question was about MySQL. Anyway, I'm not sure, better ask a separate question.

Answer (score 23):

Try like this

```
SELECT (select max(Salary) from Employee) as MAXinmum),(max(salary) FROM Employee WHERE salary NOT IN (SELECT max(salary)) FROM Employee);
```

**(Or)**

Try this, n would be the nth item you would want to return

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(Salary) FROM table ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT n,1
```

In your case

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(column_name) FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC limit 2,1;
```

Comment: your second solutions seems to be working very well. But what do you think is the problem with this simple query you've shown here. I see sub query as other's solution

Comment: limit 2,1 will fail for 2 records, which have second highest salary

Answer (score 21):

Simplest way to fetch second max salary & nth salary

```
select 
 DISTINCT(salary) 
from employee 
 order by salary desc 
limit 1,1
```

Note:

```
limit 0,1  - Top max salary

limit 1,1  - Second max salary

limit 2,1  - Third max salary

limit 3,1  - Fourth max salary
```

Answer (score 12):

The Best & Easiest solution:-

```
 SELECT
    max(salary)
FROM
    salary
WHERE
    salary < (
        SELECT
            max(salary)
        FROM
            salary
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write 2 subqueries like this example

```
SELECT (select max(Salary) from Employee) as max_id, 
     (select Salary from Employee order by Salary desc limit 1,1) as max_2nd
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Distinct sal From emp Order By sal Desc Limit 1,1;
```

It will take all `Distinct sal`. And `Limit 1,1` means: leaves top one record and print 1 record.

Comment: @Samvel Thanks for suggestion

Comment: This is a good answer. (n,m) you may use it for any level of salary.

Comment: Nice! but what if there are two persons whose salaries are same?

Answer (score 2):

```
$q="select * from info order by salary desc limit 1,0"; // display highest 2 salary
```

or

```
$q="select * from info order by salary desc limit 1,0"; // display 2nd highest salary
```

Comment: Actually thats completely wrong. Top 2 is `LIMIT 0,2` and display 2 highest is `LIMIT 1,1

Answer (score 2):

I think, It is the simplest way to find `MAX` and second `MAX` Salary.You may try this way.

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee; -- For Maximum Salary.

SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee WHERE Salary < (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee); -- For Second Maximum Salary
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that the simple way in oracle is this:

```
SELECT Salary FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary desc)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`select max(salary) as first, (select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1, 1) as second from employee limit 1`
```

For max salary simply we can use max function, but second max salary we should use sub query. in sub query we can use where condition to check second max salary or simply we can use limit.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the simplest code format :

```
 select max(salary) as 'max_salary',
 (select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1,1) as 
 '2nd_max_salary'
 from employee;
```

For finding the nth highest salary, syntax is :

```
select max(salary) as 'max_salary',
(select salary from employee order by salary desc limit n-1,1) as 
'nth_max_salary'
from employee;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write SQL query in any of your favorite database e.g. **MySQL**, **Microsoft SQL Server** or **Oracle**. You can also use database specific feature e.g. TOP, LIMIT or ROW_NUMBER to write SQL query, but you must also provide a generic solution which should work on all database. In fact, there are several ways to find second highest salary and you must know a couple of them e.g. in MySQL without using the **LIMIT** keyword, in SQL Server without using **TOP** and in Oracle without using **RANK** and **ROWNUM**.

**Generic SQL query:**

```
SELECT
    MAX(salary)
FROM
    Employee
WHERE
    Salary NOT IN (
        SELECT
            Max(Salary)
        FROM
            Employee
    );
```

Another solution which uses sub query instead of NOT IN clause. It uses `<` operator.

```
SELECT
    MAX(Salary)
FROM
    Employee
WHERE
    Salary < (
        SELECT
            Max(Salary)
        FROM
            Employee
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Find Max salary of an employee**

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
```

**Find Second Highest Salary**

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee 
Where Salary Not In (Select MAX(Salary) FROM Employee)
```

OR

```
SELECT  MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
WHERE Salary <> (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee )
```

Comment: Using inner query is not good. It only increases execution time.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will give all employee name and salary who have second highest salary

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employee
WHERE salary = (
    SELECT 
        salary
    FROM employee AS emp
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a nice query but :

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT max(Salary) from Employee
    ) as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
        WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee )) as b
ON 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For unique salaries (i.e. first can't be same as second):

```
SELECT
  MAX( s.salary ) AS max_salary,
  (SELECT
     MAX( salary ) 
   FROM salaries
   WHERE salary <> MAX( s.salary ) 
   ORDER BY salary DESC 
   LIMIT 1
  ) AS 2nd_max_salary
FROM salaries s
```

And also because it's such an unnecessary way to go about solving this problem (Can anyone say 2 rows instead of 2 columns, LOL?)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 

   SUBSTRING( GROUP_CONCAT( Salary ), 1 , LOCATE(",", GROUP_CONCAT( Salary ) ) -1 ) AS max_salary,

   SUBSTRING( GROUP_CONCAT( Salary ), LOCATE(",", GROUP_CONCAT( Salary ) ) +1 ) AS second_max_salary

FROM 
   (
     SELECT Salary FROM `Employee` ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 0,2
   ) a
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2445c/6)

Answer (score 0):

For second highest salary, This one work for me:

```
SELECT salary
FROM employee
WHERE salary 
NOT IN (
SELECT MAX( salary ) 
FROM employee
ORDER BY salary DESC
)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is awesome Query to find the nth Maximum:
For example: -

1. You want to find salary 8th row Salary, Just Changed the indexed value to 8.
2. Suppose you have 100 rows with Salary. Now you want to find Max salary for 90th row. Just changed the Indexed Value to 90.

   ```
   set @n:=0;
   select * from (select *, (@n:=@n+1) as indexed from employee order by Salary desc)t where t.indexed = 1;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

with Common table expression

```
With cte as (
 SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By Salary Desc) RowNumber, 
   Max(Salary) Salary 
 FROM
     Employee
 Group By Salary
)

Select * from cte where RowNumber = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

without nested query

```
select max(e.salary) as max_salary, max(e1.salary) as 2nd_max_salary 
from employee as e
left join employee as e1 on e.salary != e1.salary
group by e.salary desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here change `n` value according your requirement:

```
SELECT top 1 amount 
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT top n amount 
    FROM payment 
    ORDER BY amount DESC ) AS temp 
ORDER BY amount
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work same :

```
SELECT MAX(salary) max_salary,
  (SELECT MAX(salary)
   FROM Employee
   WHERE salary NOT IN
       (SELECT MAX(salary)
        FROM Employee)) 2nd_max_salary
FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query, was working for me to find Nth highest number salary.
Just replace your number with *nth_No*

```
Select DISTINCT TOP 1 salary
from 
(Select DISTINCT TOP *nth_No* salary
from Employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC)
Result
ORDER BY Salary
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to find Employee that gets 3nd highest salary then execute this query

```
SELECT a.employeeid, 
       a.salary 
FROM  (SELECT employeeid, 
              salary, 
              Dense_rank() 
                OVER( 
                  ORDER BY salary) AS n 
       FROM   employee) AS a 
WHERE  n = 3
```

What do you want

Answer (score 0):

This will work To find the **nth maximum number**

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 * from (SELECT TOP  nth_largest_no * FROM Products Order by price desc) ORDER BY price asc;
```

For Fifth Largest number

```
SELECT 
  TOP 1 *  from (SELECT TOP  5 * FROM Products Order by price desc) ORDER BY price asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    e.salary
        from(
           SELECT * FROM 
           Employee 
             group by salary
             order by salary desc
             limit 2
          ) e
     order by salary asc
     limit 1;
```

Comment: Second Largest salary

Comment: This query shown all employee list of getting 2nd highest salary.
select * from master_salary where emp_salary = (select `emp_salary` from `master_salary` group by emp_salary limit 1,1);

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which uses sub query but instead of IN clause it uses < operator

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) From Employees WHERE Salary < ( SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from emp where sal =(select max(sal) from emp where eno in(select eno from emp where sal <(select max(sal)from emp )));
```

try the above code ....

if you want the third max record then add another nested query "select max(sal)from emp" inside the bracket of the last query and give less than operator in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
  Employees where Sal >=
  (SELECT
    max(Sal)
FROM
    Employees
WHERE
    Sal < (
        SELECT
            max(Sal)
        FROM
            Employees; 
    ));
```

Comment: it isn't solution. ` 2nd_max_salary from employee` should be

Comment: can you post why you think this is a solution

Answer (score 0):

**Max Salary:**

```
select max(salary) from tbl_employee <br><br>
```

**Second Max Salary:**

```
select max(salary) from tbl_employee where salary < ( select max(salary) from tbl_employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Highest 3 Salaries in mysql

```
SELECT Salary FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary desc) AS custom LIMIT 3;
```

> Highest n Salaries in mysql, just put the value of n

```
SELECT Salary FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary desc) AS custom LIMIT n;
```