# How to find second highest salary in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find second highest salary in mysql.
All record find in second highest salary.

```
Table : Employee
ID    salary      emp_name
1     400         A
2     800         B
3     300         C
4     400         D
4     400         C

*** Mysql Query: ***
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER by salary DESC LIMIT 1,2
```

This return two record.I do not know how many record in second highest salary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find max and second max salary for a employee table MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520038/find-max-and-second-max-salary-for-a-employee-table-mysql) ... please search Stack Overflow before posting a question like this.

Comment: It is not recommended but a quick hack to your posted query us changing  LIMIT 1,1  ->limit works like this first param is from where to start, second param is how many from there to return.

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT sal
FROM emp
ORDER BY sal DESC
LIMIT 1, 1;
```

You will get only the second max salary.

And if you need any 3rd or 4th or Nth value you can increase the first value followed by `LIMIT (n-1)` ie. for 4th salary: `LIMIT 3, 1;`

Comment: Doesn't this simply give the second item on a list ? It seems to rely on salaries being unique. If two people have the same top salary, then you will simply get the second top earning person's salary, not the actual second highest salary.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT emp_name,salary 
FROM Employee
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM Employee as emp1
                WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary)=2 FROM Employee as emp2
                WHERE emp1.salary <= emp2.salary)) 
ORDER BY emp_name
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. You'd kind of hope that at 89k, you might know that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**1st one with limit-**

```
SELECT SALARY FROM tbl_name ORDER BY SALARY DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

**2nd one without limit-**

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM tbl_name WHERE SALARY < (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM tbl_name)
```

Comment: Doesn't the first example simply give the second item on a list ? It seems to rely on salaries being unique. If two people have the same top salary, then you will simply get the second top earning person's salary, not the actual second highest salary.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to find 2nd highest salary.

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

first 1 in limit is to skipping the rows and second 1 in limit is to display the row.

For third highest skip two rows same scenario to find nth salaries of the employees.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(SALARY) 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE 
    SALARY NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(SALARY) 
        FROM tbl_name
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM employee GROUP BY salary ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Above query first grouped salary column (for distinct record) and display records in descending order then apply limit function (limit function accept two parameter first one is for index(which is start from 0) and second one is for how many record we want).

If you want third highest salary just change limit 2,1 and so on for next.

Comment: You should include a description of why your code is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select salary
from (
    select salary
    from Employee
    order by desc
    limit 2) as minimumTwoSalary
order by minimumTwoSalary.salary
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY` will give you the second highest salary even if there is two same salary

```
SELECT * FROM employee GROUP BY salary ORDER by salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can find Second Highest Salary in many ways.

**1.Normal Where Condition Using MAX() Function**

```
SELECT MAX(salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee WHERE salary<(SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee);
```

**2.Using LIMIT**

```
SELECT salary AS SecondHighestSalary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC 
LIMIT 1,1;
```

**3.Using Self JOIN**

```
SELECT MAX(e2.salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee e1, Employee e2 WHERE e1.salary>e2.salary;
```

**4.Using NOT IN Keyword**

```
SELECT MAX(salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
WHERE salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to get the 2nd or nth highest salary. Basically, The DENSE_RANK()
assigns a rank to each row within a partition or result set with no gaps in ranking values.

The rank of a row is increased by one from the number of distinct rank values which come before the row.

```
SELECT salary as highest_salary FROM 
(SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY salary DESC) row_num FROM Employee) with_dense_rank
WHERE row_num = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(salary) from Employee where salary != (select max(salary) from Employee)
```

**Explanation: -**
In the above query, we are using the max function of SQL to find the maximum salary then we are comparing max salary using where clause with the help of subquery to filter out the maximum salary from the salary column.
Another example of the same approach is below. I believe it is the easiest logical method but maybe not the fastest because the subquery makes the output a bit slower.

```
select max(salary) from Employee where salary < (select max(salary) from Employee)
```

So, I will go with @Renuka Kulkarni Approach, but just a little different in the query, because some employees can also have the same amount of salary. so we need to select **Distinct**, it is important to use distinct because maybe 2 and multiple employees can have the same amount of salary.

```
SELECT DISTINCT price
FROM Product
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1, 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM employee ORDER by salary DESC LIMIT 1,1;