# 7th Highest salary in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find the row with 7th highest salary from employee table in MySQL?
I have tried it this way but unable to get the exact query.

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee 
WHERE salary NOT IN 
      (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee)
```

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: Check out LIMIT.

Comment: HINT: Use Limit  twice with different ordering  and a sub query

Comment: i think this link help you please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234983/how-to-find-third-or-nth-maximum-salary-from-salary-table

Comment: Just googling your title hits many answsers. Please read & act on [ask]. "Research"

Comment: I have put the code which i tried, but could not find the exact solution.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Hey, try something call `ROW_NUMBER()` to show the line number. Then only u take the 7th row.

Comment: see my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67261084/1147364) to find nth highest salary

Answer (score 6):

What a brief post!!! Try this though,

```
select *
from(
    select distinct salary
    from employee
    order by salary desc limit 7
) t
order by salary
limit 1
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Fixed it, add `distinct` in subquery.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use this

```
 SELECT * FROM employe ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 7
```

hope this will help you

Comment: No, just 7th highest, not all 7.

Comment: hmm , actually this select all from employe , where order use higest salary use limit 7 higest use DESC

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
SELECT *
   FROM one one1
   WHERE ( 7 ) = ( SELECT COUNT( one2.salary )
                   FROM one one2
                   WHERE one2.salary >= one1.salary
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM employees emp
WHERE 7 =
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary)
     FROM employees
     WHERE emp.salary<=salary );
```

Comment: How would this return the 7th highest salary?

Comment: @AnkitJindal Please find the link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Z61WGRokGQ
It will provide the clarification on above query