# MySQL Query To Find The Second Maximum Salary explanation required

Tags: mysql

can anyone explain how below query is working?

what concept is this?

```
SELECT salary FROM (SELECT salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2) AS Emp 
ORDER BY salary LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find max and second max salary for a employee table MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520038/find-max-and-second-max-salary-for-a-employee-table-mysql)

Comment: It seems self-explanatory!?!? What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2
```

your 1st/sub-query query returned  2 salary of the salary column(as you said limit 2), as you ordered it on descending order thats why it will return last 2 big salary

Then the 2nd query/main query will pick one  among the returned 2 row of 1st query and it will returned the minimum from the 2 salary because it is by default ordered on ascending order

```
SELECT salary FROM 
(SELECT salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2)
 AS Emp ORDER BY salary LIMIT 1;
```

For example: salary column have 10,20,30,35 records

and 
main query

```
SELECT salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2--then
```

output of this  35 and 30

Then main

```
SELECT salary FROM 
    (SELECT salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2)
     AS Emp ORDER BY salary LIMIT 1; -- it will return 30 from the upper result set
```